# How to redirect non-www to www without hardcoding using .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, 301-redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...causes a perfect, non-hardcoding 301 redirect from "www to non-www", what would the exact opposite look like?

EDIT:

According to Prix' post I've changed the `.htaccess` file to the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

As already mentioned, this redirects to `http://www./` unfortunately. Who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prix almost had it. When you negate the `RewriteCond` (with `!`) it doesn't capture so `%1` is empty. Two possible solutions:

Dummy `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`%{HTTP_HOST}` in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `^(.+)$` this will catch subdomain aswell so %1 would do odd things, not a good way to go, same with your second rule. For example, if user typed subdomain.domain.com it would try to make http://www.subdomain.domain.com/$1

Comment: No, if you typed subdomain.domain.com it would make www.subdomain.domain.com which is exactly what is asked for. I tested these rules on a running apache.

Comment: Thank you, guys - you really made my day! Without the leading "/" in RewriteRule both solutions work for me. So, which one is preferred here, maybe less "performance-sapping"?

Comment: Use the leading /. Without the leading / in the RewriteRule was causing / to appear twice. E.g., http://example.com/foo/bar was being rewritten to http://www.example.com//foo/bar

Comment: @embobo: With my Apache configuration I cannot confirm this. Using the leading "/" causes a 403 error but it's working just perfectly without it -  `example.com/foo/bar` gets `www.example.com/foo/bar` . Btw: Would it be possible to exclude subdomains from the rule(s)? `www.subdomain.example.com` looks a little strange to me... ;-) THX

Comment: And what's about forcing a trailing slash for every subfolder within the domain, e.g. `example.com/foo/bar` will be rewritten to `example.com/foo/bar/` - that would be a kind of "holy grail" IMHO... ;-)

Comment: "Use the leading /." - You should only use the leading slash on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ if these directives are in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context. In a _directory_ context (or `.htaccess` - as in the question), then the slash prefix should be removed as it simply won't match anything.

Answer (score 3):

In summation, a clean, tested version of the code:

### This works (for me) to redirect www to non-www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### Either one of these work (for me) to redirect non-www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: redirect www to non-www works well for me, +1 for dynamic domain name, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the `!` means if it does not start with "www..." then send it to `www.%1` which is the `(.+)`

Comment: thx prix! unfortunately, this rule redirects to "http://www./"

Comment: please advise...

Comment: try adding `\` before the dot on the url, i update the above code but in general it should catch %1

Comment: I've added the whole thing... anything wrong here?

Comment: Tried your fix, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm this one is harder then i expected it to be, the reason it does not receive the %1 is because the first rule is meant to catch what does not match with it so it doesnt capture anything on %1 to be used bellow, so you gona need an extra rule to detect what it got.

Comment: Not sure if this update will work aswell but give it a try and let me know, dont forget to clean you cache so it doesnt reuse pre-cached data to confuse the job. The above one might works for subdomains but might not for domain.com

Comment: Your "final" answer won't work. It will remap example.com to www.com.

Comment: well all i can say is that you need a condition to match in order to have a filled %1 or %N depending on where you set your parathensis, i dont have a server to test these rules right now but i am sure i am close :P

Answer (score 0):

The following has always worked for me with Apache 2:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yepp but I was looking for a "one-fits-it-all", non-hardcoding rule. What I really don't understand is that rewriting from www to non-www works... but not the other way round!?